# Caesar's cipher - Decryption does not work (Python)

Tags: python, encryption

I wrote a simple cryptographic program in Python.
Encryption works well but decryption doesn't.
When I enter 1 to displacement every letter works but the last (Z) does not.
When I enter 2 Y and Z will not unscramble.

An example:
Message: XYZ and displacement is 1 the result is: yza and when I unscramble it looks like this: xy`

```
choise=input("Enter 1 to encryption or 2 to decryption: ")
text=input("Enter a message: ")
displacement=int(input("Enter displacement: "))
ready=True
if displacement<0 or displacement>26:
    print("Enter 1-26")
    ready=False
print("Original message: ", text)
message=""
index=0

if ready==True:
    if choise=="1":    
        while index<len(text):
            i=ord(text[index])
            i=i+displacement
            index=index+1

            if i>ord("z"):
                i=i-26

            char=chr(i)
            message=message+char
        print("Encrypted message: ",message)


    else:
        if choise=="2":
            while index<len(text):
                i=ord(text[index])
                i=i-displacement
                index=index+1

                if i>ord("z"):
                    i=i+26

                char=chr(i)
                message=message+char
            print("Decrypted message: ",message)
        else:
            print("You have to enter 1 or 2 when choosing.")
```

Comment: Your description of the problem is a headache to be honest. Can you untangle it? Be precise about describing the problem, the output you expected and the actual output you got. And use some paragraphs, please.

Comment: Hint : When decrypting, `i` will never be greater than ord('z') but it can be less than ord('a').

Answer (score 2):

The issue is of course in `if i>ord("z"):`. It should be `if i<ord("a"):`, since you're subtracting.

Note that this will not continue to work, when you have uppercase and lowercase letters.